# Can a BEM Block have optional Elements?

Tags: css, bem

I have a "card" which looks like this:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__tag"
  </div>
  <div class="card__title">
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Is it possible to use it in another context without the `card__tag` element like so:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__title">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or should the `card__tag` element be extracted as a Mix?

I've been previously reusing blocks and in various places with elements optionally being included. I am now questioning if that is the correct approach and if the optional elements should be extracted out as their own Mix.

Comment: does it work? then yes, you can do it.

Comment: @cloned BEM is a specific methodology with strict rules on how to name things. It is not a matter of "if it works". The CSS will work no matter what class name OP uses, but that isn't the question they are asking.